# Unable to use logging in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark, pytest

I am trying to find out how to setup logging in pyspark for pytest. However both methods below has an error `TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`. I'm using python 3.7 and pyspark <2.4.0 in pycharm. Could you please help? Many thanks.

```
    logger = logging.getlogger('py4j')
    logger.setlevel(logger.WARN)

    log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    log = log4jLogger.logManager.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: Most probably this error has nothing to do with logging, but rather with the fact that some jars are not found.

Comment: @hoefling thanks. so how do I let pyspark sees those jars? I'm using this in pytest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the way you're referring to Java object is incorrect, try this instead

```py
log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger("MyLogger")
logger.setLevel(log4jLogger.Level.DEBUG)
```